# How to install ffmpeg in apache2 tomcat6 , or xampp in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, ffmpeg, xampp

I would like to know how to install ffmpeg in apache2 tomcat6 or xampp in ubuntu . So that I can dable with videos and other music files on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "*install ffmpeg in Apache2 Tomcat*".  I'm guessing that to install **ffmpeg** tools, you'd do something like `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`.  If you're looking to build from source, [this post](http://buckbox.wordpress.com/2010/12/13/installing-ffmpeg-with-h-264-on-ubuntu/) has the details.  Regarding XAMPP development, take a look at [HOWTO: Setup easy web development environment (XAMPP)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=223410)

Comment: Might also want to ask this over on http://serverfault.com/ and/or http://unix.stackexchange.com/